# Can I build one particular js file in jenkins for c# project in linux os?

Tags: git, jenkins, msbuild, mono

I am trying to build c# project in **Jenkins**. Developers developing their code under **windows** OS. I am using **linux** OS.

I have created windows slave setup and it shows successfully connected and online under log in slave node.

I am using *mono* plugin and used *xbuild.exe* path instead of *msbuild.exe* under *msbuild* path. Mono plugin also used for building c# project in linux OS.

I have entered .sln file as well as .proj file under MSBuild file. But my builds gets success even there are some errors present inside it and also I think compilation steps doesn't takes place in that build process.

What I need to do to solve this issue? Can anyone help me to find out this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of linux and mono is this

Comment: Linux is running under _3.19.0-15-generic_ and version of mono is _3.2.8_

Comment: mono 3.2.8 is really old, please upgrade

Comment: Ok Let me try with this option